# How to corrupt rpmdb?

Tags: linux, rhel, rpm, rpmbuild

Yes, You read it right i actually want to corrupt RPMDB for testing purpose.
I tried Googling it but all i got was to, how to rebuild it.

So at last i tried

```
rpm --rebuilddb
```

and killed the process in execution.

Then i verified by

```
usr/lib/rpm/rpmdb_verify /var/lib/rpm/Packages
echo $?
0
```

I need it output 1. which means that RPMDB is corrupt

Comment: Can't you just open it with a hex editor and change some bytes around?

Answer (score 0):

I just corrupted my rpm database intentionally, or at least made it so rpm errors out, which is what I wanted to accomplish. Just zero out the __db.00* files.

```
# ls -l /var/lib/rpm/__db.00*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 15 17:13 /var/lib/rpm/__db.001
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 15 17:13 /var/lib/rpm/__db.002
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 15 17:13 /var/lib/rpm/__db.003

# rpm -q filesystem
error: db5 error(11) from dbenv->open: Resource temporarily unavailable
error: cannot open Packages index using db5 - Resource temporarily unavailable (11)
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
error: db5 error(11) from dbenv->open: Resource temporarily unavailable
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
package filesystem is not installed
```